# What is the result of this lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, tuples

I'm designing a chess application in Python, and I thought I would use a lambda function to convert an input square (e.g. A3, F7...) called 'square_to' to a tuple that corresponds to the numerical position on the board (e.g. A3 corresponds to (1,3) and F7 corresponds to (6,7).
The code I wrote is:

```
square_to = input()
square_to = lambda square_to: ord(square_to[0]) - ord("a") + 1, square_to[1]
```

However, when I ran the rest of the code I got a UFuncTypeError which basically said I couldn't add/subtract a function object with other integers.
Therefore, I wanted to ask: why is 'square_to' in that code a function object and how do I access the actual results of the lambda function code that I wrote?

Comment: You have a variable named `square_to` and then redefine it to point at a lambda function `square_to` with argument `square_to`. Hard to see how this *couldn't* be confusing. Maybe you can show us how you are calling the lambda. (also, you will probably need to wrap the tuple returned from the lambda in `()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you yet understand how each symbol type works.  Let's walk through your code as it's being evaluated:

```
square_to = input()
```

`square_to` is now a simple string, the input given.

```
[LHS] = lambda square_to: ord(square_to[0]) - ord("a") + 1, square_to[1]
```

`square_to` is temporarily a free variable of the `lambda` expression; it will have to be an iterable of at least two elements.  This is unrelated to the string you just read in.

```
square_to = lambda [RHS]
```

Here, you decided to overwrite the input -- destroying it without using it -- and replace it with the `lambda` expression.  This is a sloppy way of defining a function.

So ... just what did you intend?  There is no attempt to invoke the lambda function.  I suspect that your Python version *started* the second line by binding `square_to` to a vacant-but-building lambda expression, which caused your error when you tried to use that strangely within the function definition.

> I need the function to take the raw string input of whatever the
>   player enters and convert it into a tuple with 2 entries, both of
>   which should be int types.

Then I recommend that you write such a function.  Quit playing with `lambda` until you understand straightforward function operation:

```
def square_to(algebraic):
    rank = ord(algebraic[0]) - ord("a") + 1
    file = int(algebraic[1])
    return (rank, file)
```

Obviously, you can reduce this to a single processing line (after input) with simple substitution:

```
algebraic = input()
square_to = (ord(algebraic[0]) - ord("a") + 1, int(algebraic[1]))
```

Comment: I understand that, I've always had sloppy variable naming skills lol. I want square_to to ultimately be a tuple of the square's numerical coordinates. Also, I thought that lambda functions were supposed to be anonymous, so there is no "defining" them in the traditional context, right?

Comment: I need the function to take the raw string input of whatever the player enters and convert it into a tuple with 2 entries, both of which should be int types.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = "abc"
s2 = lambda s: ord(s1[0]) - ord("a") + 1, s1[1]
s3 = s2[0]("def")
```

s2 is a tuple, s2[0] is the lambda function defined. 
s2[1] = "b" it's the second char in s1.
s3 is try to call the lambda function, and pass it an argument "def"

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.